# Windows 10, how to disable color

Tags: windows-10

Is there any possibility to remove color from Windows 10.  I basically want my whole OS to come in black and white.  I know this is an extreme question, but I used to use a small widget some time ago to get this done, is there some configuration built into windows 10 that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your graphics card, this can be done from the control software that comes with it.

For example, with an Nvidia card, you can change the following setting in the Nvidia Control Panel to effectively remove all color:

1. Expand **Display** and click **Adjust desktop color settings**
2. Select **Use NVIDIA settings**
3. Change the **Digital vibrance** setting to 0%
4. Click **Apply**.

[image]